# How to change label position of a TextBox object?

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, widget, interactive

The default position of the TextBox label is to the left of it, as shown in the image. I would like to place the label below the box. Is this possible?

Example code and image are taken from the [Matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/textbox.html).
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

t = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, 0.001)
l, = ax.plot(t, np.zeros_like(t), lw=2)


def submit(expression):
    """
    Update the plotted function to the new math *expression*.

    *expression* is a string using "t" as its independent variable, e.g.
    "t ** 3".
    """
    ydata = eval(expression)
    l.set_ydata(ydata)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    plt.draw()


axbox = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.075])
text_box = TextBox(axbox, "Evaluate")
text_box.on_submit(submit)
text_box.set_val("t ** 2")  # Trigger `submit` with the initial string.

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by manually changing the position of the label (Text artist).

Add this to the end of your script:

```py
label = text_box.ax.get_children()[1] # label is a child of the TextBox axis
label.set_position([0.5,-.1]) # [x,y] - change here to set the position
# centering the text
label.set_verticalalignment('top')
label.set_horizontalalignment('center')
```

[image: Sample TextBox with label below the box]